# PostgreSQL privilege grant not visible

Tags: postgresql

On PostgreSQL 10, I've a schema called `tn_schema` and a database called `tn_beta_db`.  I think so, although I do have to be connected to the relevant database to see the schema:

```
[T] jeff@nantes-4:~ $ sudo su postgres -c psql
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 tn_beta_db | postgres | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
(4 rows)

postgres=# \dn
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# \c tn_beta_db 
You are now connected to database "tn_beta_db" as user "postgres".
tn_beta_db=# \dn
   List of schemas
   Name    |  Owner   
-----------+----------
 public    | postgres
 tn_schema | postgres
(2 rows)

tn_beta_db=#
```

Now what's odd is that I want to grant one user the right to create tables on this schema and to do whatever necessary with those tables.  So I type this:

```
tn_beta_db=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO tn_beta_migrator;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
tn_beta_db=#
```

and the response makes me think all's well.  Though when I query,

```
tn_beta_db=# \du
                                       List of roles
    Role name     |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres         | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 tn_beta_migrator |                                                            | {}
 tn_beta_reader   |                                                            | {}
 tn_beta_writer   |                                                            | {}

tn_beta_db=#
```

it doesn't look like I've done anything.  And, indeed, when I connect as user `tn_beta_migrator`, I see I can't create tables in `tn_schema`:

```
[T] jeff@nantes-4:~ $ psql --username tn_beta_migrator --host localhost tn_beta_db
Password for user tn_beta_migrator: 
psql (10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

tn_beta_db=> create table foo();
CREATE TABLE
tn_beta_db=> drop table foo;
DROP TABLE
tn_beta_db=> create table tn_schema.foo();
ERROR:  permission denied for schema tn_schema
LINE 1: create table tn_schema.foo();
                     ^
tn_beta_db=>
```

I'll note that I also tried this, which doesn't change the outcome:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;
```

Any pointers on what I've misunderstood?

### Update

I have three users, to be clear: one that is read-only, one that is r/w-only, and another with full table modification permissions.  The goal is that the tables created by the user allowed to do so are readable by the reader and read-writable by the read-writer.

Following feedback, I've issued these commands:

```
    -- Connect to the correct db, as schemas are part of databases.
    \c tn_beta_db

    -- For future tables, these are the privileges I want to see.  Note
    -- that I need to alter the privileges for the role in question,
    -- even though I grant to the role as well.
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_reader \
        GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO tn_beta_reader;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_writer \
        GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON TABLES TO tn_beta_writer;
    ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA tn_schema FOR ROLE tn_beta_migrator \
        GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO tn_beta_migrator;

    -- This wasn't a problem, but to be explicit, I do want
    -- all three roles to be able to connect.
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_reader;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_writer;
    GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE tn_beta_db TO tn_beta_migrator;

    -- While I'm doing this at a time when there are not yet any tables
    -- in the database, it would be good to for this script to work
    -- even at some later time.  So here I grant the appropriate rights
    -- to those tables that might already exist, as ALTER DEFAULT
    -- does not change privileges for existing tables.
    GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_reader;
    GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_writer;
    GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;

    -- And finally, I note that this role is allowed to create tables.
    GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;
```

With these modifications, tn_beta_migrator is able to create tables, but can't select, insert, or update from them nor can it drop them again.

### Update: solution

Following suggestion by @laurenz-albe, I made a new minimal example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654544/postgresql-create-a-schema-fail-to-grant-privileges).  That led to an answer.  For those who follow, the issue was that I'd forgotten to grant usage:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;
```

Comment: Changing default privileges doesn't change any actual privileges on the existing tables, it will only assign privileges by default as soon as a certain user creates new tables.

Comment: Right, but I executed the privilege change before anyone created a table.  Then I still can't create a table.

Comment: `GRANT ALL ON TABLES` doesn't contain the privilege to create a table, grants on table objects are for using that table. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html - the table creation privilege is part of the schema object.

Comment: Thanks!  This indeed lets me create tables as tn_beta_migrator.  But select, insert, update, and drop remain forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

A list of things you misunderstood:

1. [`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) does not change the permissions on any existing object, in your case the schema.

   You need to [grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-grant.html) the [`CREATE` privilege](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-priv.html) on the schema:

   ```
   GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator;
   ```
2. The `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statement you ran will only affect the permissions on tables created by user `postgres` in schema `tn_schema`, but it seems that you want `tn_beta_migrator` to create tables.

   You don't need `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` at all, since the user that creates the table becomes the table owner and has all privileges on the table by default.
3. You can view default privileges with `\ddp` in `psql`.
4. Schemas are part of a database, so you need to connect to the database to see its schemas.

If you want that the tables created by `tn_beta_migrator` get certain permissions by default, you must define default privileges **for that user** (and not for `postgres`, like you did):

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE tn_beta_migrator IN SCHEMA tn_schema GRANT ...;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's quite helpful, also the links.  And, indeed, executing `GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA tn_schema TO tn_beta_migrator` allows me to create a table.  I am then denied permission to insert into it or to drop it.  Rereading the privilege page suggests that CREATE is a schema permission but INSERT and DROP are table permissions, and so my ALTER DEFAULT should have handled that.

Comment: (There exist some other users with lesser permissions, `tn_beta_reader` and `tn_beta_writer`.  This was the intention of the ALTER DEFAULT PERMISSION, that any tables that `tn_beta_migrator` creates are automatically readable or r/w-able by those other two.)

Comment: You have to define default privileges for the user that creates the tables, not for `postgres`, as indicated in the updates to my answer.

Comment: Thanks!  What you've written makes sense, but perhaps despite reading the docs further, I've misinterpretted something.  So I've provided an update at the end of the question.

Comment: That seems like a different question. Perhaps you need to change ownership of the existing tables.

Comment: This is initial db setup.  I have _no_ tables.  The goal is to govern who will be able to access the tables I create and with what permissions.  Of course, I'd like to be be able to correct an existing table, but that's not necessary if everything is set up correctly at first and no assumptions ever change.  Today, there are no tables.  Except `foo` and `bar`, which I've created and dropped a few dozen times. ;-)

Comment: The user who created the tables can do anything with them, Your code looks ok. Maybe you should come up with a self-contained test case that demonstrates the problem and ask a new question for that.

Comment: I've added a self-contained example case above that starts from no database, no schema, no user and proceeds to the error.

Comment: ^^ Ignore that comment, but SO won't let me change it anymore.

Comment: Sure, I've created a simple and reproducible case as a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654544/postgresql-create-a-schema-fail-to-grant-privileges).

Comment: That was a very good suggestion: it led to an answer, that I had forgotten to grant `usage on schema`.